# Can you rebase on latest commit?

Tags: git

I would like to rebase branch B onto A. But I don't want to merge 10 times, since A has been updated a lot.

How is it possible to merge onto the latest of A (in order to merge only once)?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking... Isn't `git checkout B; git rebase A` enough?

Comment: Either you are rebasing or merging, I do not understand what you are doing.

Comment: @Alessandro Vendruscolo yes but when you do this, you go through all commits that happened on A. I only want to merge the latest commit on A with latest on B

Comment: @Mateusz You can have conflicts while rebasing

Comment: Even when merging 10 commits you only have to resolve conflicts once. When rebasing 10 commits you might be required to fix the conflicts for each of the commits.

Comment: @knittl. 'When rebasing 10 commits ..' -> this is what I'm doing now. But isn't it possible to do this all in once (using the latest version)?

Comment: The same as you would do with regular merging actually

Comment: Why don't you use `merge`?

Comment: that would give me the wanted result, but I want to rebase to have a better looking tree

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`git merge --squash`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) which will take all commits from a branch, squash them into a single commit and put it on top of the current commit (without creating a merge-commit). Note that you will lose all information how the changes got there in the first place, you will only have a single large commit with *all* changes.

Comment: Yes it seems that squassing together all my commits & than rebase is the only solution. But then I lose my commit information

Comment: You can either resolve the merge conflicts as a single commit once and lose commit information, or you can resolve conflicts multiple times and keep commit information. Both is not possible (Just think about it: Each commit must apply cleanly to its parent(s))