# Git rebase only latest commit?

Tags: git

I think my question has been previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725841/can-you-rebase-on-latest-commit), but it's been eight years so figured I'd post to see if anything has changed/if there's anything I can do.

I am taking over an **old** project that is midway through completion and has ~20 commits made to its feature branch. Since the work was done, many commits have been made to master, and I need to bring it current. Our company wants all work to be rebased on master, never merge. The problem is, when I rebase, it rips through ALL of the old work (20 commits) one by one. **Is there a way to rebase only the latest commit to bring all this work current without squashing all of these previous commits?**

Comment: What do you want to happen to all the old commits?

Comment: (Basically if you could make this more concrete in terms of the current situation and the desired result, it would be much easier to help you.)

Comment: Nothing has changed here since the existing question.

Comment: Good question. I guess therein lies the problem. Basically I am wondering there's a way to bring the feature branch current and preserve all this commit history without having to rebase every commit individually each time we want to rebase (which will be fairly often now since we're about to start actively working on it to get it across the finish line)

Comment: If you want to rebase all the commits, you need to rebase all the commits. Period.

Comment: If your goal is to preserve the commit history, then your only options are 1: A non-fast-forward merge, or 2: rebase every commit. This would never change since no other solutions would make sense. This seems more like a policy-issue.

Comment: Note that in general, if you're "reactivating" some sort of long-dormant work, you'll have one big burst of adaptation-to-current, followed by much smaller adjustments as you go. That corresponds to the "one big rebase with a ton of work, followed by smaller rebase-or-merge steps" that you're dreading here: it's just how things are.

Comment: Sometimes—but only sometimes!—you can ease the pain of the "one big burst" step by splitting it into repeated smaller-bursts: pick some point(s) in history between "then" and "now", and do repeated rebases onto each of those points. This may actually be more work overall but might give you more points at which you can do proper testing or have other assurances that are valuable in their own right, and hence might be worthwhile. Or it might not! That's one of those software engineering judgment calls.